# How to add time stamp values into MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have two time stamps one for entry and another for exit.

I have the data field time1,time2 and it's datatype is timestamp.

When i add this entry and exit time into database, it displayed 0.0.0.0 - 0.0.

Why it's displayed like this. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please amend your question with an example `INSERT` query you're using.

Comment: And an example SELECT too.

Answer (score 0):

You should INSERT in below format to table:

> INSERT INTO `sakila`.`test` (`time1`, `time2`) VALUES ('2013-07-08
>   19:27:05', '2013-07-08 19:27:09');